# Generating a spline from centers of multiple mesh

Tags: python

As you can see in the image below:

[image]

I need to find an approximating spline (with least deviation of centers from the spline).

Next I want to get perpendicular normal to the spline passing through each center.

Any help could be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the normals part, but you can easily create a bezier curve running through selected object centers with the builtin Btrace addon.

Under *User Preferences > Addons* activate the BTrace addon.

In the *3D View ToolShelf > Create > Btrace* choose *Object Connect*.

Select the desired objects and press the *Run* button at the bottom of the panel.

[image]

If you desire a smooth curve, you can then enter *Edit Mode* on the created bezier and change handle type to *Smooth* by selecting all vertex pressing <kbd>V</kbd> > *Automatic*.

[image]

Not sure how you want your normals represented, curves have a builtin *Offset* property from the *Properties Editor > Object Data > Offset* which allow you to add an offset to the original curve, but you can't easily access the resulting points coordinates.

[image]

You may optionally extrude the curve slightly and convert to mesh, then access face normals.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! 

Could you please elaborate the part when you try to smooth the curve. I'm unable to see a smoothed version of my curve. 
What I did is - Select the curve > Edit Mode > V > Automatic. 

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That is it. Make sure you have selected vertex before changing handle type, otherwise nothing happens

Comment: @RahulNalawade  the locus of all unit length lines perpendicular  to the curve could be created by adding unit circle following curve path tracking its face normal at the knot.   How would you pick one? the greatest in Z direction?

Comment: @batFINGER you are right. I think I oversimplified the question asked above. So, first we want to make sure that the curve we get is in 2D (not 3D as mentioned above by Mr. Ramos). So, the curve we get from the centers, which is approximated to be planar, will have the 2 normals we need - one perpendicular to the plane of the curve itself, and the other perpendicular to the curve in the same plane, both passing through the center points. That way, we dont have to pick any normals.