How to generate a plane for a moving animation? Generated at the very edge


How to generate a plane for a moving animation? Generated at the very edge.

What does this mean?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79445/using-boolean-modifiers-and-shape-keys-in-animation/79449#79449 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135475/generating-a-spline-from-centers-of-multiple-mesh/135478#135478 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52830/is-it-possible-to-create-a-path-from-an-existing-object-animation/52831#52831
